# what difference, when using objectify?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

Ask from [here](https://github.com/mpxr/Foodely/blob/master/api/src/main/java/hu/iit/bme/api/model/ProfileEndpoint.java)
what difference between:

```
Profile profile = ofy().load().type(Profile.class).id(userId).now();
```

and

```
Profile profile = ofy().load().key(Key.create(Profile.class, userId)).now();
```

why we must create key for userId using `Key.create(Profile.class, userId)`? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference is that the first example does a key query by defining the key implicitly. The second defines the key explicitly.

Both will result in the very same key query.

You don't have to create the key for userId explicitly. But that way it's more obvious what you're doing.